# Read UTF-8 encoded file that includes 4-byte encodings into Excel

Tags: excel, utf-8, vba

The recommended technique for reading UTF-8 files is:

```vb
  Dim FileStream As Stream
  Dim FileBodyADO As String

  Set FileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  With FileStream
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile ("C:\DataArea\Resources\VBA Outlook\Tutorial\examples.json")

    FileBodyADO = .ReadText()

    .Close
  End With

  Set FileStream = Nothing
```

However, if you attempt to read “examples.json” which is part of the archived SO documentation, the statement `FileBodyADO = .ReadText()` never finishes.

A UTF-8 file is a byte orientated file (unlike, for example, UTF-16) with characters whose codes are in the range 0 to &H7F carried unchanged and characters with codes above &H7F encoded to multi-byte sequences:

```
  -Code (Hex)-  ---------------Encoding---------------
  Start    End    Byte 1    Byte 2    Byte 3    Byte 4
      0     7F  0xxxxxxx
     80    7FF  110xxxxx  10xxxxxx
    800   FFFF  1110xxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
  10000 10FFFF  11110xxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx  10xxxxxx
```

“examples.json” contains:

```
92,601,220 1-byte encodings
     8,848 2-byte encodings
    20,122 3-byte encodings and
       166 4-byte encodings.
```

The 1-byte encodings are ASCII characters. The 2-byte encodings are, for example, § (HA7) and I (H131). The 3-byte encodings are, for example, √ (H221A) and 年 (H5E74). The 4-byte encodings are, for example, “Sparkling heart” (H1F496) and “Smiling face with smiling eyes” (H1F601).

I can find nothing to suggest that Office products can handle characters with codes above U+FFFF.  I suspect that `ReadText` ends in an endless loop when it hits a 4-byte encoding.

I have my own VBA routine for decoding an UTF-8 file.  It too failed to process 4-byte encodings when they were first encountered. I have since enhanced/corrected my routine to accept 4-byte encodings and to decode them as numeric character entities.  For example, “Smiling face with smiling eyes” (H1F601) is carried in the file as HF0 9F 98 81 which my routine decodes to `&amp;#x01F601;`.  If this numeric character entity is placed in an html file, Microsoft Edge displays the correct emoji.  I understand Google Chrome and most (all?) modern browsers can also handle such numeric character entities.  What can you see: 😁?  Since the text that includes these characters is html, my solution is adequate for my current requirements.

I will post my routine as an answer in a few days unless a better answer is posted first.  Do people agree that ADODB’s `ReadText` is defeated by 4-byte encodings?  Can Office products, and in particular Excel, handle Plane 1 Unicode characters (H10000 to H1FFFF)? Is there an alternative to my use of numeric character?

**More background**

I have accepted the answer from Tom Blodget because it does answer my question.  However, it is not the answer I hoped for.

Some years ago I was receiving files in different formats that included UTF-16, UTF-8, ASCII and ISO-8859-1.  The authors of these files were extracting data from different applications but I found the variety of formats unexpected; in my experience, most applications use UTF-8 these days.  None of my suppliers knew what format their source application created or how to change the output format to UTF-8 or something consistent.

“Traditional VBA” will read or write ASCII or Unicode (by which Microsoft means OCS-2) files.  Apparently OCS-2 is “virtually identical” to UTF-16.  To me, “virtually identical” means different but I can find nothing to explain how they differ.  ADODB is a VBA library that will accept other formats but all the documentation implies you have to know what that format is.  Utilities like NotePad++ will open any text file and tell you its format.  I could find nothing similar with VBA.

I decided I had to write my own code to read each file into a byte array and identify the format.  Identifying the format was not much less work that identifying and converting to a VBA string so that is what I did.  The files were not particularly large so the read and conversion was taking less than .01 seconds which was adequate for my needs.

When I needed to read “examples.json” I naturally used my routine.  I now know that “examples.json” contains 166 4-byte encodings and that my routine did not handle them correctly.  I fixed the bugs in my routine and was pleased with the result except that it took 34 seconds with the latest version to process the 92Mb file.  I tried ADODB to see how much faster it was but it never terminated.  That was how far I had got before I asked this question.

I had read that ADODB was not very efficient and that you should read a small block at a time.  However, I did not equate “inefficient” to “does not terminate” until I tried Tom Blodget’s answer.  By optimising the use of ADODB as suggested, it now terminated.  Studying the output increased my understanding of UTF-8 encoding so this was a useful exercise.  However, at about 40 seconds, ADODB was even slower than my VBA routine.

On my laptop, the following code reads the entire 92Mb file into a byte array in about .1 seconds:

```
  FileNum = FreeFile
  Open PathFileName For Binary Access Read As FileNum
  ReDim FileBodyByte(1 To LOF(FileNum))
  Get FileNum, , FileBodyByte
  Close FileNum
```

Once in a byte array, the conversion to a string is totally processor-bound. Why does ADODB need the block to be read in 128K blocks?  What happens if a block ends in the middle of an encoding?  Why does it take so long?  I have converted processor-bound VBA routines to VB.Net and got durations down by a factor of 1,000. I would not feel comfortable using ADODB is a routine I released to a client.

Microsoft seems to be obsessed with forward compatibility.  VBA code I wrote 15 years ago still works.  Microsoft does not enhance old routines; it introduces new libraries if new functionality is to be provided.  ADODB is old.  I was hoping for something new and better rather than a work-around.

Comment: No, ADODB.Stream handles UTF-8 encoded characters with 4 code units just fine. The problem seems to be something else, perhaps the file size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ADODB.Stream.[ReadText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/readtext-method) documentation explains an efficiency problem and proposes reading fewer bytes at a time to mitigate it.

So,

```
  Dim FileStream As Stream: Set FileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

  With FileStream
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile "C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\examples.json"

    Dim FileBodyADO As String: FileBodyADO = ""
    While Not .EOS
        FileBodyADO = FileBodyADO & .ReadText(128 * 1024&)
    Wend
    Debug.Print Len(FileBodyADO)
    Debug.Assert Len(FileBodyADO) = 92630322
    .Close
  End With

  Set FileStream = Nothing
```

As .NET independently tells you, examples.json contains text that UTF-16 encodes with 92630322 code units.  (VBA/VB4+ uses UTF-16 strings [as do so many other languages since the early 1990s].)

```
File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Tom\Downloads\examples.json").Length == 92630322
```

Comment: I considered efficiency issues but rejected them as a reason. I left `ADODB.ReadText` for an hour before aborting it. My VBA routine takes 28 seconds to decode this 92Mb file. I would expect `ADODB.ReadText` to be faster. What would `ADODB.ReadText` decode 4-byte encodings to?  I cannot find any documentation that states/suggests/implies that a VBA string or an Excel string could hold characters with codes above U+10000. The documentation I have found recommends holding an emoji as an image if wanted within Excel. Please link to appropriate documentation if you know differently.

Comment: I will experiment with your code.  If it works for me, I will try to discover what the 4-byte encodings have decoded to.  My count of the code points was higher than the value you got although that could be an error in my code for counting them.  Having said that, multiplying my counts by encoding lengths gives the correct file length.

Comment: Microsoft tended to call the USC-2 encoding of the Unicode character set "Unicode" and then applied that to its replacement, UTF-16, too. The difference between USC-2 and UTF-16 is not something that is typically a language or library  issue. [ChrW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chr-function) documentation is barely interpretable and the term "character" is ambiguous but ChrW just deals with a UTF-16 code unit; Put two together in a string as necessary for a codepoint >U+FFFF and you are done.